# Does a monk's robe allow an additional use of redirection?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, feats, class-feature, monk

Would the additional Stunning Fist use from wearing a *monk's robe* apply to a flowing monk's special ability redirection?

According to the [*monk's robe*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/robe-monk-s/):

> If donned by a character with the Stunning Fist feat, the robe lets her make one additional stunning attack per day

And according to the feat [Stunning Fist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stunning-fist-combat-final/):

> A monk may attempt a stunning attack a number of times per day equal to his monk level, plus one more time per day for every four levels he has in classes other than monk.

And according to the archetype [flowing monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/flowing-monk/) that trades Stunning Fist for the special ability redirection:

> A flowing monk can use this ability once per day per monk level, but no more than once per round. This ability replaces Stunning Fist.

Because the ability redirection remains limited to once per day per monk level, would a *monk's robe* instead enable a flowing monk another use of the ability redirection once per day?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If a [*monk's robe*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/wondrous-items/wondrous-items/r-z/robe-monk-s/)'s wearer doesn't have the feat [Stunning Fist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/combat-feats/stunning-fist-combat-final/), the wearer gains no benefit from that aspect of the *monk's robe*, even if the wearer *could have had* the feat Stunning Fist. The [flowing monk](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/monk/archetypes/paizo-monk-archetypes/flowing-monk/) archetype's extraordinary ability redirection just *isn't* the feat Stunning Fist, and the *monk's robe* can't help him with the ability redirection instead.

However, I strongly recommend asking the GM to make available a *flowing robe* for the same price that replaces the *monk's robe*'s extra Stunning Fist use per day with an extra redirection use per day. Such a minor change shouldn't be *unbalanced*—the game, after all, *already* thinks the ability redirection a fair trade for the feat Stunning Fist—, and having this *flowing robe* means *you* won't be bitter about your PC paying for a feature of a magic item that your PC can't use.

Comment: @DanceSC You're welcome. One of the big problems with taking an archetype is that the *rest of the game* is, for the most part, still writing about the class *without* the archetype, leaving many cool character *concepts* bereft of class-feature-enhancing magic items *in play*. There's no real fix for this *except* asking the DM. Hope everything works out.

Comment: Oh I'm not too worried about it, the item would be primarily for the other features. But it doesn't hurt to ask.